# Suppress a low-level error message in LuaTeX

Tags: errors, luatex, tex-core

Using LuaTeX it is possible to customize low-level error messages produced directly by TeX, such as the undefined control sequence error, or bad number etc.  Here is the code that David Carlisle wrote at [Custom error message for bad length value?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409293/).

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
function my_error ()
local e =status.lasterrorstring
if(e=='! Missing number, treated as zero') then
  texio.write_nl ('! Missing number,\string\n\space\space perhaps you should look at page 6')
else if(e=='! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)') then
  texio.write_nl ('! Illegal unit of measure\string\n\space\space you really should look at page 6 of the documentaion')
else
  texio.write_nl(e)
end
end
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('show_error_message',my_error,'error message hook')
}
\begin{document}

\setlength\oddsidemargin{x}

\newcommand\cos{\sin}

\end{document}
```

However, this does not suppress the error.  In view of a possible application to automatically defining missing variants in `expl3` code, I'm wondering if it is possible to completely suppress the error and do something else entirely.  I'm particularly interested in the case of the "Undefined control sequence" error.

Comment: I suppose you could make luatex always be in scrollmode and then re-implement the user interaction modes in lua in this callback, so the following error behaviour will never stop and if you want it to stop after the message you would have to code that interaction in lua, perhaps...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle One would also need to make sure the exit status is not messed up I guess.

Comment: I'll leave the details to you:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Probably the more reasonable thing to do in practice would be to make the error message say "Missing variant! Write `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \foobar:Nn { cV }` in a package or between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`." Then make it insert the appropriate TeX tokens. (And expandably perform the definition of the variant within LuaTeX probably.)

Comment: That's currently not possible, even though backend support is almost there in [`show_error_hook`](https://github.com/reviczky/luatex/blob/4b893cdd030328a9cec0beaa16defe02b5791d26/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/errors.w#L398-L401).